# npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10(and minimatch@0.2.14) Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

Tags: cordova, npm, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I am getting following warnings while installing phonegap cli(on windows 7 -64bit). I first installed phonegap desktop then i installed node.js(npm -v => 2.15.9) and when i used "**npm install -g phonegap**" command code,i got following warnings.

Could any one tell me how to fix the warnings ?My goal is to utilize phonegap plugins by using phonegap cli.Thanks in advance.

**Warnings while installing phonegap cli:**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\smith>npm install -g phonegap
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls g
raceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
C:\Users\smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap -> C:\Users\smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js
phonegap@6.3.2 C:\Users\smith\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap
├── opener@1.4.1
├── pluralize@0.0.4
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── semver@1.1.0
├── minimist@0.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── update-notifier@0.6.3 (is-npm@1.0.0, semver-diff@2.1.0, chalk@1.1.3, boxen@0.3.1, configstore@2.1.0, latest-version@2.0.0)
├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.4.0, read@1.0.7, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)
├── phonegap-build@0.10.0 (colors@0.6.2, qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, optimist@0.3.7, shelljs@0.0.9, phonegap-build-api@0.4.0)
├── insight@0.8.2 (object-assign@4.1.0, async@1.5.2, tough-cookie@2.3.1, node-uuid@1.4.7, lodash.debounce@3.1.1, chalk@1.1.3, os-name@1.0.3, configstore@1.4.0, request@2.75.0,
 inquirer@0.10.1)
├── connect-phonegap@0.23.0 (home-dir@0.1.2, ip@0.3.1, connect-inject@0.3.2, adm-zip@0.4.7, request-progress@0.3.1, http-proxy@1.8.1, shelljs@0.2.6, walkdir@0.0.11, useragent@
2.0.8, request@2.33.0, node-static@0.7.0, gaze@0.4.3, socket.io@1.4.6, tar@0.1.19, localtunnel@1.3.0, connect@2.12.0, archiver@0.14.3)
└── cordova@6.1.1 (underscore@1.7.0, q@1.0.1, ansi@0.3.1, nopt@3.0.1, update-notifier@0.5.0, cordova-common@1.4.1, cordova-lib@6.1.1)

C:\Users\smith>
```